# why jquery-chosen not working inside tabs in angular-ui

Tags: angularjs, tabs, angular-ui, jquery-chosen

```
<tabset  class="ui-tab">
    <tab heading="General Details">
      <select class="chosen chzn-done chosen-select">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="1">contains</option>
          <option value="2">does not contain</option>
          <option value="3">is equal to</option>
      </select>
    </tab>
</tabset>


 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".chosen").chosen({
        no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!",
        allow_single_deselect: true,
        width: "20%"
    });
});
```

This is the code I have tested. Here the dropdown of chosen is not working but working correctly on out side of the `<tabset>`. How should I solve this ?

Comment: why you don;t go for angular chosen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The angular way is to create a directive for jQuery plugins.

I've created one simple for the jquery-chosen you mentioned. Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/skvEcsN9UVYsG8YxjqmV?p=preview):

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.directive('chosen', function(){
  return {
    link: function(scope, element){
      element.chosen({
        no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!",
        allow_single_deselect: true,
        width: "20%"
      });
    }
  };
});
```

**EDIT**:
There is already a library to integrate *jquery-chosen* to *angular*: [angular-chosen](https://github.com/localytics/angular-chosen)